# In-App purchase returned with error code 1001 in iphone?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have an iPhone application in which when i am trying to purchase something in the sandbox, it is returning error code 1001 cannot connect to itunes. But this code was working fine 30 minutes ago. I have been testing this for days and working fine. Suddenly this comes. And I have tried all possible answers, like logging out of the store, uninstall and installing it again. Nothing seems to be working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you working on the simulator or a device? Is the Internet connection reliable?

Comment: I am working in ios5 simulator,But when i tested in the device also it is giving me this error.in ios5 simulator it is working fine couple of hours before this error happend