# Always get state SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing of In_app on iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I use tutorial what use MKStoreKit

I added my products ID

But then i try make buy process i always get transactionState SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing

In Apple Dev Guide no words when it comes and what i must to do with it.

I try different devices, different mac pc's and else.

But always get state SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing

And it on all products TypeConsumable or not.

Can help me what is this error? And what my next steps when i get this state?

Comment: More people is experiencing problems with the sandbox environment just now: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125714/www-sandbox-itunes-apple-com-is-down) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109425/in-app-purchase-returned-with-error-code-1001-in-iphone). This suggests to me that the problem could be on Apple's end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happen because Apple need time to Product create in "servers" maybe.

So this sutiation is:

In 12:00 i create Product with ID:org.example.testProduct

And only on next day i can work with it.

Seems like Apple nedd time to "synchronize" data between servers or smht.

Answer (score 0):

Do you recieve it in the Simulator?

It comes, when Apple's popover with "do you want to purchase the item?".

Then it changes to purchased or failed, but notvin the Simulator.